# Do I need to own Orgins to play Awakening

Tags: ps3, dragon-age-origins, dragon-age-origins-awakening

I really like DAO, but I am just burrowing it from a friend. I have found DAW for pretty cheap and I want to play it, but am I limited to playing it only while I still have DAO.

I know it is an expansion, and from my pc days I was able to play the original using the expansion CD. I don't expect that here, but what are the limitation of an expansion on PS3.

Comment: Do you have a DAO character already on the PS3?

Comment: Yes, I have the character already, but I have not completed it yet.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend burrowing any video games ever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - **Do I need to insert my Origins disk to play Awakening?**
>
> If you are only playing Awakening, you do not need to swap discs on
>   any platform. **Simply start Dragon Age with your Awakening disc and
>   away you go!**

Many more common questions regarding the expansion pack are answered in the source below.

[Source here](http://social.bioware.com/forum/Dragon-Age-Origins/Dragon-Age-Origins-Awakening-General-Discussion-NO-SPOILERS/Dragon-Age-Awakening-Launch-FAQ-1759884-1.html)

More information per the source:

> On PlayStation 3 and Xbox 360 console, start up Dragon Age with the
>   Awakening disc in the drive, then press New Game. Select Awakening
>   campaign icon.
>
> - How do I import my DA:O character?
>
> To import your Dragon Age: Origins character into Awakening:
>
> For PC:
>
> Select OTHER CAMPAIGNS at the start menu.
>
> Select Dragon Age: Awakening from the list of campaigns.
>
> Select IMPORT FROM ANOTHER MODULE at the next screen.
>
> You will be presented the character from your last played save game.
>   Select IMPORT, or choose ADVANCED to select another save game you wish
>   to use
>
> For Console: To import your Dragon Age: Origins character into
>   Awakening:
>
> Start Dragon Age with the Awakening disc in the drive.
>
> Select NEW GAME at the start menu.
>
> Select the Awakening icon.
>
> At the character creation screen, select IMPORT CHARACTER
>
> Choose save game to import
>
> In all platforms, if the character had not yet reached level 18, they
>   will be elevated to that level instantly.
>
> - What level do new Grey Wardens start at?
>
> If you create a new Grey Warden for your adventure in Awakening they
>   will start at level 18.
>
> All specialization, attribute, talent and skill points will be
>   unassigned, allowing you to customize your character from the very
>   start.
>
> - Will my items transfer to Awakening when I import my character?
>
> Most items will import into Awakening from Origins. All items obtained
>   from the Return to Ostagar DLC will transfer. Weapons, armor and other
>   items that are unique to all other DLC releases will not transfer.
>
> Your storage chest at Warden's Keep will not be accessible and items
>   stored in it will not transfer to Awakening. Be sure to go back and
>   retrieve anything you think you might want before importing your
>   character to Awakening. You will have a new storage chest at Vigil
>   Keep once you are in Awakening.
>
> - Do I have to complete the base game to import my character?
>
> No. You do not have to complete the base game to import your
>   character. However completing Dragon Age: Origins may open different
>   options for your character in Awakening.
>
> When I try to install my Awakening expansion the auto-installer
>   freezes and returns an "Installation Failed" message.
>
> There is a potential workaround, which can be found in the Dragon Age
>   Customer Support Site:
>   http://help.dragonage.com/cgi-bin/eadragonage.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?&p_faqid=46545

Comment: So I only need the disk for the part of the story that I want to play? Do I need to beat Origins before moving to Awakening? Is it import only or does it start with the level I am on.

Comment: Correct.  & You can import a character in the menu system of Awakening for all characters over the level of 18. Otherwise, if you select new game it will generate a new character for you with the level 18. See my edit for more information from that source.

Comment: Perfect that is exactly what I needed to know. Thanks!

Comment: Anytime, hope it helped :)

Comment: Do you even need to have origins to play awakening? If I can create someone from scratch do you even need to have DAO to play DAW? I would assume that is used some of the same game data so you would at least need it installed on the console?

Comment: That I cannot confirm as I have it for PC, which just installs into DAO.  I would presume as no as you are given the option to create a new Grey Warden in Awakening ( which receives an insta-boost to level 18)